# Prevent listview items from showing in a second column

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working with Winforms using C#.

It is easier to explain my question with a screen shot:

The list view on the left, notice how items15 and later are showing in a second column. I don't want that. I want it to have a vertical scroll bar and items15 to appear under item14, etc..not in a new column. I have set the "view" property on "List" too.

[image]

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Set

```
listview.Scrollable = true;
listview.View = View.Details
listview.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None;
```

Add a dummy column, its an important step, cause we changed the View to *details*:

```
    ColumnHeader header = new ColumnHeader();
    header.Text = "MyHeader";
    header.Name = "MyColumn1";
    listView.Columns.Add(header);
```

Comment: now it shows the vertical scroll bar but doesn't show ANY of the items inside listview.

Comment: I provided example code, u need to add a dummy column, then it should work