# Listview items text is trucncated and doesn't show it all

Tags: c#, winforms

I am usign a code a code like this and when the text gets long, it cuts it off and doesn't show the whole text :( In this aspect I want it to behave like a list box item. One line was for one item in the list box and didn't have this trucnacted text issue.

```
    listView1.Scrollable = true;
    listView1.View = View.Details;
    listView1.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None;

    ColumnHeader header = new ColumnHeader();
    header.Text = "MyHeader";
    header.Name = "MyColumn1";
    listView1.Columns.Add(header);

    listView1.Items.Add("TooLongTextDoesntShow");
    listView1.Items.Add("short");
    listView1.Items.Add("abcd");
```

I think it is just easier to attach a picture of the issue. Please notice how it is not displaying full text of the highlighted item :(

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: @seekerOfKnowledge: yeah the dummy column was because of the answer I got for my other question in here, please let me know if there are better ways for that too, thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703449/prevent-listview-items-from-showing-in-a-second-column/10703670#10703670

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just specify a column header width.

```
 ColumnHeader header = new ColumnHeader();
 header.Text = "MyHeader";
 header.Name = "MyColumn1";
 header.Width = listView1.Width //Same Width as Entire List Control
 listView1.Columns.Add(header);
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative ways to do, is *during* the add.

You can make use of: [ListView.ColumnHeaderCollection.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/497zcd0k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public virtual ColumnHeader Add(
    string text,
    int width   //width of the header
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a solution, please let me know if there are better ways of doing it too

**AFTER** adding items to list view is done, we should call this:

```
listView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
```

Comment: @seekerOfKnowledge: yeah the dummy column was because of the answer I got for my other question in here, please let me know if there are better ways for that too, thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703449/prevent-listview-items-from-showing-in-a-second-column/10703670#10703670

Answer (score 0):

We take an example of ListView with 2 columns and resize on contents and then to minimum width.

```
// Auto resize of ListView Columns to minimum width
private int[] ColumnsWidth = { 35, 322 };

/// <summary>
/// Resize the columns based on the items entered
/// </summary>
private void ResizeColumns()
{
    // Auto Resize Columns based on content
    m_urlsListView.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
    // Make sure to resize to minimum width
    if (m_urlsListView.Columns[0].Width < ColumnsWidth[0])
    {
        m_urlsListView.Columns[0].Width = ColumnsWidth[0];
    }
    if (m_urlsListView.Columns[1].Width < ColumnsWidth[1])
    {
        m_urlsListView.Columns[1].Width = ColumnsWidth[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The content is being truncated because of (practically invisible) column. You can tell the `ListView` to adjust the column widths automatically:

```
listView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
listView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a column and define its width according to your text size requirement. Moreover "Scrollable" property can be set to true if the actual width of the listview control is smaller

[ListView_Column_Width_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnvUY.png)